# How to throw an exception in the Promise catch method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, throw

What I want to do is to execute some sync/async functions back-to-back in the chain and - if something is not right - reject this function, catch this rejection in the `catch` method at the end of the chain and simply throw an exception for the user. I'm writing a module and I want the user to have some messages thrown if he/she configure the module incorrectly.

When I try to throw an Error in the Promise `catch` method, it returns `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection` exception.
As I found out, the JS 'treats' the `throw` similarly to `reject()` and it expects another `catch` method attached at the end of the following chain to 'catch' this thrown Error, what seems to be a little confisung to me, or maybe I don't get the idea of promises...

```
test()
.then(()=>{
  console.log('success!');
})
.catch((msg)=>{
  throw new Error(msg);
});
//it expects another catch here to 'catch' the thrown error
//if I attach another catch() here
//then the 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning' is not displayed
//but Error is still not thrown, just caught by another catch()

function test(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      reject('you set incorrect type!');
    },300);
  });
}
```

I could throw an error directly in the Promise object in order to throw an exception and terminate the chain flow as I want, but what I've also found a little confusing is that I can use `throw` only asynchronously in the Promise object to throw an exception. If I `throw` synchronously, the Promise `catch()` method catches this exception.

This throws error: *(which is desirable)*

```
function test(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      throw new Error('async aborted!'); 
    },300);
  });
}
```

This executes Promise `catch()`: *(which is **not** desirable)*

```
function test(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    throw new Error('sync aborted!');
    setTimeout(()=>{

    },300);
  });
}
```

So, to sum up, I try to figure out how to to throw Error without getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection` exception?
In the `try catch` block I can simply re-throw an exception, why I can't do so in the Promise chain?